# How to get user claims details in Program.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

In our application, we use a third-party tool for authentication (OIDC), and once authentication is done, we are fetching the user claims details like roles, names, and others details in the home controller (~website/home) as shown below. There are times the user is hitting the other page directly (~website/Department) instead of the home URL; our application is still getting authenticated, but user details like roles and names are not getting assigned.

Only when I hit Home Screen again, these details get assigned.

Is there a way to read claims data in Program.cs before App.run() or any other best practice?

```
`
//Home Controller
 public IActionResult Index()
 {
     var roleId = UsersRoles();
    
     return view();
}

 public int UsersRoles()
{
     foreach (var claim in User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == Corp.Role))
     {
         int roleType = int.Parse(claim.Value);

         
     }
    return roleType;
 }`
```

After Authentication, we have assigned user details like Name, Roles in Home Controller. But sometime users are launching the other web pages instead of Home page, and user details like Name, Roles are not getting assigned to variables.

We want to either redirect application to Home page for want to read user Authentication details from Program.cs itself.

Comment: The index method will only run when there is no parameters.  It must mean that the call to Index has parameters.  I usually in these cases add a break point in UserRoles and then look at the Stack Trace to see how it was called.

Comment: Don't assign the roles on index in your home page, use OIDC's event callbacks to capture the identity and do your work.

Answer (score 0):

You can centralize the retrieval of user claims details by creating a service that loads the necessary information once after authentication and then makes it available to any part of your application that requires it.

1)Create ClaimsPrincipal Service

```
public interface IUserClaimsService
{
    int GetUserRole(ClaimsPrincipal user);
}

public class UserClaimsService : IUserClaimsService
{
    public int GetUserRole(ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
        var roleClaim = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == Corporative.Role); // Replace with your actual role claim type
        if (roleClaim == null) return default;

        return int.Parse(roleClaim.Value);
    }
}
```

2)Now register this service in Program.cs file:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsService, UserClaimsService>();
```

3)Use the Service in Controllers:

```
public class DepartmentController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserClaimsService _userClaimsService;

    public DepartmentController(IUserClaimsService userClaimsService)
    {
        _userClaimsService = userClaimsService;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        int userRole = _userClaimsService.GetUserRole(User);
        // Use the role as needed...
        return View();
    }
}
```

If you still face missing claim data you could redirect user to the `HomeController`.Implement this check at the beginning of action methods that require the claims data, and then redirect users if needed

```
public IActionResult SomeAction()
{
    if (!_userClaimsService.HasRequiredClaims(User))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    // Rest of your action logic...
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be done with `Authorize` attributes and specifying a [custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies)? Your solution probably works but why reinvent the wheel when the standard ASP.NET Core infrastructure already provides all the functionality?

Comment: @UweKeim it depends on the needs. this ClaimsPrincipal Service can help manage more complex requirements. also when claims are required deeper in the application, such as in service layers or business logic, where `[Authorize]` attributes are not applicable.otherwise you can also prefer Authorize attributes for simplicity and framework-level integration.